# Building Sokoban Game using Actionscript 3, and getting incorrect number of arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arguments

I've been doing this Sokoban game for the university, however, I'm stuck with something. Here's the code so far on AS3:

```
    package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var levels:Array=new Array();
        private var currentLevel:uint = 0;
        private var tile:tiles_mc;
        private var level_container:Sprite;
        public function Main()
        {
            setupLevels();
            drawLevel(currentLevel);
        }

        private function setupLevels():void
        {
            levels[0]=[[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,2,0,0,3,0,1],
               [1,0,3,0,0,2,4,1],[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]];
            levels[1]=[[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
               [1,0,3,5,2,4,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]];
            levels[2]=[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
               [1,3,3,3,1,1,1,1],[1,6,2,0,2,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]];
            trace("My levels: "+levels);
        }

        private function drawLevel(level:uint):void
        {
            level_container = new Sprite();
            addChild(level_container);
            for (var i:uint=0; i<levels[currentLevel].length; i++)
            {
                for (var j:uint=0; j<levels[currentLevel][i].length; j++)
                {
                    switch (levels[currentLevel][i][j])
                    {
                        case 0 :// floor
                            tile = new tiles_mc(1,i,j);
                            level_container.addChild(tile);
                            break;
                        case 1 :// wall
                            tile = new tiles_mc(1,i,j);
                            level_container.addChild(tile);
                            break;
                        case 2 :// crate goal
                            tile = new tiles_mc(1,i,j);
                            level_container.addChild(tile);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }}
```

However, when I try to test, I get this error:

[image]

What's going on? Clearly AS recognises the arguments, as seen here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the definition of `tiles_mc`.

Comment: is the tiles_mc class "exported for actionscript" from a library? if yes, check if the base class is properly set